После добавления файла через запрос в Postman, бесконечно происходит Sending request
У меня есть функция, которая загружает файл в определенную директорию и заносит информацию о файле в бд, проблема в том, что при запросе в постман, происходит бесконечное выполнение запроса. При этом, сам файл в директорию загружается и данные появляются в бд. Т.е. проблема именно в бесконечном выполнении запроса. В идеале, после завершения должен выводится json с таким сообщением: message: 'File uploaded successfully'
Вот код функции:
const uploadFile = (req, res) => {
    upload.single('file')(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error during file upload:', err);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'File upload failed' });
        }

        const { file } = req;
        if (!file) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
        }

        const fileData = {
            name: file.originalname,
            extension: path.extname(file.originalname).slice(1),
            mimeType: file.mimetype,
            size: file.size
        };

        fileModel.addFile(fileData, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error saving file to database:', error);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Database error' });
            }
            res.status(201).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully', file: fileData });
        });
    });
};

Вот переменная upload (конфигурация для multer)
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});


const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;


а что у вас в переменной upload? покажите её инициализацию

Это конфигурация для multer, сейчас добавлю в основной пост

попробуйте всё, что внутри callback-а, завернуть в try/catch c выводом исключения в лог

Все так же, ошибок не возникает, просто бесконечная загрузка
